# Simle/Nested foreach to linq( Concatenate string and Datatable rows and columns)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

Is there a way to change this foreach loop in LINQ.
here Dict is my dictionary and builder is a stringbuilder.

```
string str = "m";
string seperateChar = str + "n";  
foreach (string column in dict2.Keys)
{
   builder.Append(str)
          .Append("\"")
          .Append(column)
          .Append("\""); 

   //builder.Append("\"");

   str = seperateChar;     
}
```

I was trying to apply nested loop on this query, can this be done too through LINQ 
Lets assume its a row and columns.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {

                    var res = "m" + String.Join("mn", table.Columns.ColumnName.Select(k => "\"" + k + "\""));
            writer.WriteLine(res.ToString());

                }
```

Comment: I have a feeling this loop doesn't do what you think it does. Have you tested it? Can you give some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return "m" + String.Join("mn", dict2.Keys.Select(k => "\"" + k + "\""))
```

Comment: This does the same as the OP? Where are the \'s?

Comment: Don't you need `dict2.Keys.Select(k => "\"" + k + "\"")` or similar?

Comment: Test code: http://rextester.com/BEOA23546 - compares original code to this answer. Same result so +1

Answer (score 0):

```
return "m\"" + dict1.Keys.Aggregate((a, b) => a + "\"mn\"" + b) + "\"";
```